# How to avoid horizontal elements being displaced within a navbar when the display width is small?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am new to web front-end development, though I have backend and embedded programming experience.

I am learning front-end development by using Bootstrap. I wrote this simple bootstrap code (available [on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3sq2a8s6/)) as an exercise.

What I am observing is that the elements of the `navbar` stack up vertically when I view the output on a 240px wide display. How do I stop the elements of the `navbar` from stacking-up vertically, and instead maintain it's horizontal alignment when the display width is reduced. If I remove the `select` element from the `navbar`, then the "toggle bars button" on the extreme right of the `navbar` remains horizontally aligned with the "navbar brand" on the extreme left. But if the `select` element is added next to the "navbar brand", then the "navbar brand", the `select` element and the "toggle bars button" stack-up vertically.

Also, when the display size is increased to various different sizes(I am using Firefox's Responsive Design View tool to test this), at one point, i.e. when the display width is 768px or less, the horizontal-form which has two text-edits and two button elements is displayed on the next row of the "navbar brand". How do I avoid the horizontal-form moving to next row? What I want is, when the "toggle bars button" converts to the horizontal-form it should align horizontally with the "navbar brand" and `select` element rather than move to the next row.  In short, I want the elements of the `navbar` to always remain horizontally aligned irrespective of the display width.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I stop the elements of the navbar from stacking-up vertically, and instead maintain it's horizontal alignment when the display width is reduced.

Move elements into `<div class="navbar-header"></div>`.

And you can remove the toggle button if you don't use it.

> if the select element is added next to the "navbar brand", then the "navbar brand", the select element and the "toggle bars button" stack-up vertically.

Try to add this style:

```
.form-group {
  float: left;
}
```

> when the display width is 768px or less, the horizontal-form which has two text-edits and two button elements is displayed on the next row of the "navbar brand".

Try to merge both forms together. Check the code below. Is it what you want to achieve?

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/rgsyfwc9/

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.form-group {
  float: left;
}
.navbar-form {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
.navbar-header {
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand">
        Brand
      </a>
      <form class="navbar-form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Test 1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text 2">
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```